# Trading card game poss

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, likelihood

A trading card game that is called *Flesh and Blood* (description and rules [here](https://fabtcg.com/resources/learn-to-play/)) has two players construct a 60 card deck and the hand limit is 4. Player 2's Deck color combination: 60 cards in deck; 34 are blue, 17 are red, and 9 are yellow. Statistical scenario: Player 1 is at 26 Health Points and has 1 card in hand. Player 2 has 4 cards in hand(3 blues and 1 yellow) and 1 card(red) face down on the table. Player 2 can only win if the top card of their deck (Y) and card in Player 1's hand is (X):

X(P1)/Y(P2):

red/red = Win

red/yellow = Win

red/blue = Win

yellow/red = Lose

yellow/yellow = Win

yellow/blue = Win

blue/red = Lose

blue/yellow = Lose

blue/blue = Lose

Winning Scenarios/Total Scenarios = 5/9 or 55.6% to win.

My question is: Do I need to add the percentage of what colors are left in Player 2's deck when the scenario above is conducted? During this scenario, Player 2's deck is at 45 cards. 4(3 blue and 1 yellow) of them in hand, 1(a red) on table, and 10 in Graveyard(4 reds, 3 yellows, and 3 blues). Player 2 adds -1 to every red and yellow and +1 to every blue. With the combination of hand and graveyard color count, Player 2 will be at a Blackjack Count of -3, showing a slight chance to see a blue over reds and yellows.

34 blues/60 deck size = .5667 or 56.67% to have a blue be the top of the deck at the start of the game. -1/+1 to the total count of blues in the deck, shows it has a difference of +/-1.66%. When I am at a count of -3, I do this: 1.66x3= 4.98%. So an increase of 5% to see a blue on top

2 of the 3 blue combinations, Player 2 wins, so 67% chance to win if its a blue on top. Do I add the 5% to the win probability?

Let me know if this is too confusing or not.

Comment: *"2 of the 3 blue combinations, Player 2 wins, so 67% chance to win if its a blue on top."* assuming that the Player 1 has equal probability to have blue red or yellow in their hand.

Answer (score 0):

Using these black jack counts makes it too complicated. Player 2 can accurately compute the composition of the remaining cards in the deck.

$$\begin{array}{}
\text{red} &=& 17 - (4+0+1) &=& 12 \\ 
\text{yellow} &=& 9 - (3+1+0) &=& 5 \\ 
\text{blue} &=& 34 - (3+3+0) &=& 28 \\ 
\end{array}$$

If each of the 45 cards has equal probability to be a top card then the probability for a blue card on top is 28/45 ≈ 62.2%.